# What can be implemented to prevent any tables from being changed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Q2. You want to prevent changes to tables in one of the databases in your SQL Server instance since
changes to any of the tables can cause the associated client application to stop functioning. What can be implemented to prevent any tables from being changed?
a. A stored procedure
b. A database‐level DDL trigger
c. A DML trigger
d. A server‐level DDL trigger

thanks

Comment: The answer is in the book the question came from...http://books.google.com/books?id=DzZ1VJPLLQoC&pg=RA1-PA31&lpg=RA1-PA31&dq=%22You+want+to+prevent+changes+to+tables+in+one+of+the+databases+in+your+SQL+Server%22&source=bl&ots=ReM_srmIjQ&sig=FIpYDOa9XYNPtd_wMDAr5-B_iDY&hl=en&ei=dNYATp-6HKTb0QGYwvDLDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22You%20want%20to%20prevent%20changes%20to%20tables%20in%20one%20of%20the%20databases%20in%20your%20SQL%20Server%22&f=false

Comment: Google Books has an answer: http://goo.gl/tRicz (from: *The Real MCTS SQL Server 2008 Exam 70-432 Prep Kit*)

Comment: Homework?  Isn't this in the textbook? Or a google search?

Comment: Did you look up each of the terms above? I mean, I don't mind helping a student work through a tough problem, but if you can't figure out the answer to that one with the information given then you have no business passing the class. It's two minutes of work with Google or your text book.

Comment: It's B incase anyone reads this and the link goes dead. (Out of the choices available)

Comment: wow, the word 'brazen' comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Proper security.

Don't give your app accounts with owner rights.